# The visible results on abs small or big

Tags: workout, abdominals

I am doing abs and I wonder how will be in future if I still workout.Specific to topic,4pack, 6 pack,8 pack is caused by genetics.The issue is I see some guys have visible  small abs 4 pack and others have big-huge 4 pack. This happen to 6 pack too.In 8 pack not much difference.My question is if I  continue doing abs my abs become huge? How a guy have huge abs and some others have small abs ,both have visibles abs.(is caused by genetic and that ? Or is variety of different workouts ?what?) .Thanks

Comment: genetics + fat layer

Comment: also, workout matter, as well

Comment: Less fat =bigger abs ,fat= smaller  abs ?did I understand right?

Comment: No, that's not accurate. Sure, there is some amount of genetics involved, but abs are just like any other muscle. If you work them out, they will grow. But, if you have a lot of fat, they will be hidden behind a layer of fat, and less visible. But large abs behind a lot of fat is still large abs. The less fat you have, the more your abs can protrude, giving them the "look" that most people are after.

Comment: @s.m well I think Jun Kang is right

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments the abs are just like any other muscle in our body.Yes,their shape depends on our genetics and there is no way to change that but their size can be changed.

To achieve that you just need to train your abs just like any other muscle for **hypetrophy** because you can also have strong abs but not aesthetically beautiful (ex powerlifters,strongmen etc).

Now,assuming you already have both strong and "big" abs all you got to do is lose some fat and let them unveal.This might sound simple but it requires a lot of effort with diet and tracking your macros.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh ..............."As mentioned in the comments the abs are just like any other muscle in our body." Noooo...............................................................................................

Comment: Where is the problem? I said that because someone had already answered but in this site most of you don't know where to write the answers so I wrote an answer in the right place

Comment: The "abs" are anything but the same as other muscles, even just looking at the rectus forgetting the inner core.

Comment: I agree with the Mike-DhSc that's why I don't accept the answer

Comment: The question isn't about how the abdominal muscle work rather than how to make them look bigger so I don't see any reason to get into details. If you do hypertrophy for the abs they get bigger that's a fact if you expected anything else I am sorry but that's how it is.

Comment: The first sentence you wrote doesn't make sense.I ask how work the abs and why some guys have bigger. What is this hypertrophy as I see is no physical way( may I don't understand if you would like explain more ) .Everyone who has bigger abs is hypertrhope?  Sounds weird.Don't know .I would like to see someone else answer .Thank you Spyros anyway

Comment: I apologise since English is not my native language. As for hypertrophy I thought you knew because it's one of the basic things when you start working out, so I assumed you knew what it is.My fault again. You can see about hypertrophy here or just Google it your self as there are far two many things to say. https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/hst1.htm